# WebApi - Access and validate models in Filters

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I created a filter to be used from actions that receive Models as parameters. The idea is to return a 400 before the request gets to the action itself.

Here's the filter:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        Log.Debug("");

        var _return = new BaseReturn<object>();
        _return.Success = false;

        try
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid && actionContext.ActionArguments[actionContext.ActionArguments.Keys.First()] != null) 
                return;

            if (actionContext.ModelState.Values.Count == 0)
                _return.Message = "Model not sent";

            if (actionContext.ModelState.Values.Count > 0 && actionContext.ModelState.Values.Any(c => c.Errors.Count > 0))
                _return.Message = actionContext.ModelState.Values.First(c => c.Errors.Count > 0).Errors[0].ErrorMessage;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _return.Message = ex.Message;
        }

        if (_return.Message == null)
            _return.Message = "Model is not valid";

        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse<BaseReturn<object>>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, _return);
    }
}
```

And this is my action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Devices/{id}/SendOrder")]
[ValidateModel]
public BaseReturn<bool> SendNotificationToDevice(string id, OrderNotification model)
{
}
```

The problem here is that ModelState is only trying to validate the {id} parameter. It **does** validate my model if I remove {id} from the method declaration.

Is there a way to make ModelState validate both parameters ?

Well...it seems that ModelState **does** validate the model even with {id} in the method declaration. The only problem is that I couldn't find a way to discover (in the OnActionExecuting method) if the OrderNotification model was sent or not.

When I send an empty JSON, ModelState.Values.Count is 1 and since {id} is present in the URL, ModelState.IsValid is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in ASP.NET Web API, `null` object parameter values are not treated as invalid. If you want to treat these as invalid you can update your filter to first process the parameters to ensure they have a value set:

```
        foreach (var parameter in actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters())
        {
            object parameterValue;
            if (!parameter.IsOptional
                && parameter.ParameterType.IsClass
                && actionContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue(parameter.ParameterName,
                out parameterValue))
            {
                if (parameterValue == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(parameter.ParameterName, "");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> To force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the
>   `[FromUri]` attribute to the parameter

have you tried to add `[FromUri]` attribute to your parameter?

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("api/Devices/{id}/SendOrder")]
  [ValidateModel]
  public BaseReturn<bool> SendNotificationToDevice(string id, [FromUri]OrderNotification model)
  {
  }
```